# Using bash command to copy files from a subfolder to another

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have the following structure:

```
.
├── dag_1
│   ├── dag
│   │   ├── current
│   │   └── deprecated
│   └── sparkjobs
│       ├── current
│       |    └── spark_3.py
│       └── deprecated
│           └── spark_1.py
│           └── spark_2.py
├── dag_2
│   ├── dag
│   │   ├── current
│   │   └── deprecated
│   └── sparkjobs
│       ├── current
│       |    └── spark_3.py
│       └── deprecated
│           └── spark_1.py
│           └── spark_2.py
```

I want to create a new folder getting only current spark jobs, my expected output folder is:

```
.
├── dag_1
|    └── spark_3.py
├── dag_2
     └── spark_3.py
```

I've tried to use

```bash
find /mnt/c/Users/User/Test/ -type f -wholename "sparkjob/current" | xargs -i cp {} /mnt/c/Users/User/Test/output/
```

Although my script is not writing the files and returns me no error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, `install` command take the input file and copy it to another dir structure, creating the whole tree of dirs if necessary as `mkdir -p` transparently:

(you need to add wildcard `*` in `-wholename` to effectively find files)

```
find . -type f -wholename "*/sparkjob/current/*" -exec bash -c '
    dir=${1#./} dir=${dir%%/*} file=${1##*/}
    install -D "$1" "./$dir/$file"
' bash {} \;
```

##### Exemple of what is done:

```
install -D ./dag_2/sparkjob/current/spark_3.py ./dag_2/spark_3.py
install -D ./dag_1/sparkjob/current/spark_3.py ./dag_1/spark_3.py
```

The source path is an example, if longer, no issue.

Answer (score 2):

First you should check what `find` returns by removing everything after `|`. You'll see `find` doesn't find any files. The reasons:

- as the name implies, `-wholename` matches the whole name, so you need `*/sparkjob/current/*`
- according to your `tree` output, the folder is not named `sparkjob` but `sparkjobs`.

I'd start with something like this:

```
find /mnt/c/Users/User/Test/ -type f -wholename "*/sparkjobs/current/*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo mv "$file" "$(realpath "$(dirname "$file")"/../..)"
done
```

I added an `echo` so you can check all paths and commands are correct.

You may want to trade simplicity for performance. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 if performance is important (many files or frequent runs).

Comment: This will break on files with spaces

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yes, changed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do:

```bash
mkdir ../new_folder
find . -type f \
       -path '*/sparkjobs/current/*' \
       -exec sh -c 'f=$1
                    new=${f/sparkjobs\/current\//}
                    dest="../new_folder/$(dirname "$new")"
                    mkdir -p "$dest"
                    cp -v "$f" "$dest"' sh '{}' \;
```

```
‘./dag_1/sparkjobs/current/spark_3.py’ -> ‘../new_folder/./dag_1/spark_3.py’
‘./dag_2/sparkjobs/current/spark_3.py’ -> ‘../new_folder/./dag_2/spark_3.py’
```

Answer (score 1):

This *looks* pretty straightforward.

```
for d in $old_loc/dag_*
do mkdir -p "$new_loc/${d##*/}"
   cp "$d"/sparkjobs/current/spark_*.py "${d##*/}"
done
```